# Media Queries - Center Content

Tags: html, css, media-queries

When my website is full size, I have content in the footer aligned to the left and right, as follows;

```
<div class="site-info">
<span class="left">© Client 2016</span>
<span class="right">Site by<a href="#"><img class="credits-img" src="http://voicecoaches.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/john_text.png" width="50px" align="right"></a></span>
</div>
```

Using this CSS;

```
.right {
   float: none;
}

.left {
   float: none;
}
```

When the website is displayed on a phone, I want the content in the span classes to be displayed in the middle of the screen, with the '© Client 2016' text being displayed on one line, and the text/image link being displayed on another line below it, both centered. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: How about `text-align: center`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using `flexbox`

```css
.site-info {
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}
.right img {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .site-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: lightgray;
  }
  .right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .right img {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-info">
  <span class="left">© Client 2016</span>
  <span class="right">Site by <a href="#"><img class="credits-img" src="http://voicecoaches.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/john_text.png" width="50px"></a></span>
</div>
```

And if you can't/don't want `flexbox`, here is one without

```css
.site-info {
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}
.right a {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .site-info > span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .right * {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .right a {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-info">
  <span class="left">© Client 2016</span>
  <span class="right">Site by <a href="#"><img class="credits-img" src="http://voicecoaches.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/john_text.png" width="50px"></a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine! Now time to research on how it works.

Comment: @RonaIdo That's the fun part :) ... added a 2:nd sample to keep you busy

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Screens up to 480px wide*/ 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, .right {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Add this to your css and if the screen size is less then 480px it will do this code instead.

You can read more about the @media rule here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get each span class to display on a separate line when using the media query? That's the bit I'm having trouble with mainly.

Comment: Add a display: block; to the css inside the media query

Comment: No change at all :/. I'm not sure what is wrong, I have a bit of experience in HTML / CSS so thought this would have been easy enough but I must be missing something somewhere.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Far easier and works in all browsers where flexbox does not.